# jwt value is null but cookie have value how can I check?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, jwt

1. this controller login

   ```
    [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string aimUserMail, string aimUserPassword)
    {
        var user = _sql.AimUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AimUserMail == aimUserMail && x.AimUserPassword == aimUserPassword);

         return BadRequest(error: new { message = "UserEmail or password is not correct" });
        //}
        if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(error: new { message = "UserEmail or password is not correct ...." });
        }

        var jwt = this.jwt.Generete(user.AimUserId);
        Response.Cookies.Append("jwt",jwt, new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            Secure = true
        });
        return Ok(user);
    }
   ```
2. this is controller check auth :

   ```
       [HttpGet("user")]
       public IActionResult User()
       {
        try
        {
            var jwt = Request.Cookies["jwt"];
            var token = this.jwt.Verify(jwt);
            int aimUserId = int.Parse(token.Issuer);

            var user = _sql.AimUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AimUserId == aimUserId);
            return Ok(user);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }


    }
   ```

Comment: why did you add react.js tag

Answer (score 0):

Your jwt is null, seems you have add return method in your login function.

[image]

If you want get all cookie, you can try below code. Then you can check what you want.

```
    [HttpGet("GetAllCookie")]
    public IActionResult GetCookie()
    {
        int count = Request.Cookies.Count;
        var CookiesArray = Request.Cookies.Keys.ToArray();
        List<CookieObj> list = new List<CookieObj>();
        CookieObj o;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            o = new CookieObj();
            string cookieKey = CookiesArray[i];
            o.cookiename = cookieKey;
            o.cookievalue = Request.Cookies[cookieKey];
            list.Add(o);
        }
        return Ok(list);
    }
    public class CookieObj { 
        public string cookiename { get; set; }
        public string cookievalue { get; set; }
    }
```